# How to put horizontal scrollbar in Pagination Material UI component in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, pagination

I am using a pagination material UI component in my application to display list of numbers from where user can actually choose the number and proceed it for further processing.

[image]

I have got one more requirement here to show the horizontal scrollbar with this component so that the user need not to click on right arrow every time he/she wants to select the number.

The user should be able to use a horizontal scrollbar to scroll through the list of numbers.

Is it possible using this component or any other component in react?

Thanks,
Jyoti

Comment: Can you use the Snippet tool in your question to display the code you're using. Make sure you include references to the MaterialUI library you're pulling from. Can't do much with a picture and we need to know what you've tried or are trying.

Comment: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-pagination/ .. This is the reference of pagination component